# How to use jquery sortable to sort a list of tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have many table rows where each few belong to a different group, what I want to have is that each rows that belong to the same group will be in a different table, and to be sortable inside this table (which is easy to do), but I also want those tables of groups to be also sortable so you can drag the **whole** table and reorder it within those other tables..

I tried making a main sortable table which will have the groups tables inside which contain the sortable records.

Here is an illustration of what I mean

```
Table 1
-----------------------------
Field 1 | Field 2 | Filed 3 |
-----------------------------
R1C1    | R1C2    | R1C3    |
-----------------------------
R2C1    | R2C2    | R2C3    |
-----------------------------

Table 2
-----------------------------
Field 1 | Field 2 | Filed 3 |
-----------------------------
R1C1    | R1C2    | R1C3    |
-----------------------------
R2C1    | R2C2    | R2C3    |
-----------------------------
```

Here those tables (Table 1 and Table 2) places can be swapped (reordered) include all their content of course.

Much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to wrap the individual tables in a div and add a `handle` element to the div. I'm assuming you are using jQueryUI sortable which has a `handle` option for draggables and sortables

HTML:

```
<uL>
   <li>
        <div>
            <div class="handle"></div>
            <table> </table>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('table').sortable({items:'tr'});
$('ul').sortable({
    items:'li',
    handle:'.handle'
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fYx4D/1/

Comment: Ah! that's a great turn around!